# python generate histogram/pareto chart on keywords

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, highcharts

I have a huge list of words, such as `['abc', 'def', 'python', 'abc', 'python', ...]`

1. How do I generate a list/dictionary that I can plot into a histogram/Pareto chart, such as:
   `{'python': 10, 'abc': 8, 'def': 2,...}`
2. Also, what would be a suitable charting library to visualize the above word occurrence sorted from high to low?

Comment: Hi. The second question is asking for a recommendation for a software library and as such is off-topic for Stackoverflow ([help/on-topic]). Such question might be fit in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are those numbers counts of occurrences of each unique word?

Answer (score 2):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) offers a convenient and relatively fast way to create a dictionary like the one you show:

```
from collections import Counter

x = ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs', 'ham', 'chips', 'eggs',  'spam', 'spam', 'spam']

counts = Counter(x)
print(counts)
# Counter({'spam': 4, 'eggs': 2, 'ham': 2, 'chips': 1})
```

To visualise the counts, you could use a [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) bar chart:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# sort counts in descending order
labels, heights = zip(*sorted(((k, v) for k, v in counts.items()), reverse=True))

# lefthand edge of each bar
left = np.arange(len(heights))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.bar(left, heights, 1)
ax.set_xticks(left + 0.5)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels,  fontsize='large')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get a word count:

```
lst = ['abc', 'def', 'python', 'abc', 'python']
wordcount = {}
for word in lst:
    wordcount.setdefault(word,0)
    wordcount[word] += 1
```

Plotly seems like a god choice for creating charts with python: https://plot.ly/python/histograms/